# Extract specific files from zip every single folder that matches in my given name in jszip

Tags: jszip

var JSZip = require('jszip');

var fs = require('fs');

const  error = require('console');

fs.readFile('/home/id13/Videos/test.zip', function(err, data){

```
if (!err){

    var zip = new JSZip();

    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function(zip){
```

var count = 0; zip.file(*/*asswords?).forEach(function (file) {

```
          file.async('string').then(function(content) {

           

            var fileName = file.name.split('/').pop(); // get the file name without the folder path

            fs.writeFile('/home/id13/Passwords?' + fileName, content, function(err) {

              if (err) {

              console.error(err);

              }

              else  {

                  count++; 

              console.log('File ' + fileName + ' saved!');

              // check if all files are extracted

              if (count <= zip.file('*/*asswords?').length) {

                console.log('Operation success!');

              }

              }

          })

              }).catch(function (error) {

              console.error(error);

            })

          })

        }).catch(function(error){

        console.error(error);

    });

}
```

});

This  code extracts specific files from zip files but after extracts 1 folder his stop how to extract all files from all zip folders that's match in test.txt

```
 When extracts all file then saves to one folder
```